# Como puedo enviar el value de el option seleccionado a una funcion?

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes, actualmente lo que estoy queriendo hacer es lo siguiente:

Tengo un `<select>` que tiene múltiples categorías con una id cada una, lo que quiero hacer es que en el caso de que se cambie este select, osea en un `onChange`, se envié como argumento a una función x, el value de esta opción seleccionada, o el id si hubiera que hacerlo de otra forma.

Mi select

```
<select>
        <option default> ---- Select Category ---- </option>

        {this.state.items.length ?
        this.state.items.map(item=>

        <option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>

            ) 
        : <li>Loading...</li>
      }
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontre la solucion,

```
<select onChange={this.selectKey.bind(this)}>
```

```js
selectKey(event) {  
  this.setState({ exampleState: event.target.value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion mas simple, podria ser la siguiente

```
<select onChange="alert(this.value)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Esto en react no funcionaria del todo, debe hacerse como lo dice la respuesta de santiago.